# how to make visual basic work on protected worksheets (no password on protection)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a work book with several worksheets that I would like to protect. I am not using a password on the protection. I have some visual basic code associated with this sheet to expand the row width on merged cells. The code will not work when the sheets are protected.

I did find some guidance on adding unprotect code to my code, but can't figure out where to put it and how to address the fact that there is no passord. Further guidance woudl be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     Dim NewRwHt As Single
     Dim cWdth As Single, MrgeWdth As Single
     Dim c As Range, cc As Range
     Dim ma As Range

     With Target
        If .MergeCells And .WrapText Then
            Set c = Target.Cells(1, 1)
            cWdth = c.ColumnWidth
            Set ma = c.MergeArea
            For Each cc In ma.Cells
                MrgeWdth = MrgeWdth + cc.ColumnWidth
            Next
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ma.MergeCells = False
            c.ColumnWidth = MrgeWdth
            c.EntireRow.AutoFit
            NewRwHt = c.RowHeight
            c.ColumnWidth = cWdth
            ma.MergeCells = True
            ma.RowHeight = NewRwHt
            cWdth = 0: MrgeWdth = 0
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You could probably do something like this:

Surround your code with `.Unprotect` and `.Protect`

```vb
Sub protectSheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets(1)

    With ws
        .Unprotect "password"

        'Insert Code Here

        .Protect "password"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wSheet As Worksheet

For Each wSheet In Worksheets

    wSheet.Protect Password:="Password_here", _
    UserInterFaceOnly:=True

Next wSheet

End Sub
```

Put this code in 'ThisWorkbook' then use the `Workbook_Open` Event.
This code protects all the WS everytime you open the WB
but allows macro to run due to `UserInterfaceOnly` set to `true`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to protect the sheet with password.
2. If you want a user to edit some cells even if the worksheet is protected then set the locked property of those cells to false before protecting the sheet.
3. Now when `Worksheet_Change` is triggered or any procedure is called which is trying to make some changes to excel range (locked cells = true) then you need to Unprotect the Sheet at beginning of the code and protect it at the end again. You may refer @sobin answer for syntax.
4. Also you may use error handlers and explicitly protect the sheet. This is done to avoid situation wherein the sheet is unprotected and then there is error which comes up for any reason then that would leave the sheets unprotected.